# What is the historical origin of this hat [image] - worn by Pope Ratzinger

Tags: papacy

Can anyone explain the origin — i.e., when it was first used, the Pope who wore it the first time and when, its name —  of that red hat worn by Pope Ratzinger?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Pope Emeritus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Emeritus#Retired_bishops) Benedict XVI (formerly known as Joseph Cardinal Ratzinger) is depicted above wearing what is known as a ["cappello romano,"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappello_romano) which is Italian for "Roman hat."

It does not originate from papal attire, but was simply a fashionable hat worn by 17th century clergy.

From wikipedia:

> A cappello romano (literally Roman hat in Italian) or saturno (because
>   its appearance is reminiscent of the ringed planet Saturn) is a hat
>   with a wide, circular brim and a rounded crown worn outdoors in some
>   countries by Catholic clergy, when dressed in a cassock. It is made of
>   either beaver fur or felt, and lined in white silk. Unlike many other
>   articles of ecclesiastical attire, it serves no ceremonial purpose,
>   being primarily a practical item.  The cappello romano is not used in
>   liturgical services. Since the general abandonment of the cassock as
>   street dress, it is uncommon even in Rome today, though it was quite
>   popular there and in some other countries with a Catholic majority
>   population from the 17th century until around 1970.
>
> There are some, mostly minor, differences in the designs of cappelli,
>   depending on the rank of the wearer. The pope wears a red cappello
>   with gold cords. Cardinals formerly also had the privilege of wearing
>   a red cappello, but this rule was overturned by Paul VI, and now
>   Cardinals' cappelli are black, as are those of all other clerics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It seems that Orthodox Jews wear a similar-looking hat with a broad brim.

Comment: When in Rome... :)